# Upgraded Tortoise version, used Upgrade Working Copy, Commit then failed .svn/tmp/svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I reinstalled windows and thus grabbed a newer copy of Tortoise (1.8) and found that I needed to use the "Upgrade Working Copy" of my local repo in order to use the features available.

After doing so I then attempted to commit and received the following error:

Can't create temporary file from template mypath /.svn/tmp/svn-XXXXXX: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by creating the tmp folder inside of the .svn folder as it seems to have been missing.  Afterwards it appears to have committed.